# jquery validate with conditional custom method. Condition not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate that a select box value is greater than zero, only if another condition exists.  I have a range of things in place, and from what I can tell it should work, but it's not.

My Custom Validation Method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThanZero", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (parseFloat(value) > 0);
}, "* Amount must be greater than zero");
```

This works fine (in that it validates that address_stateid is greater than zero): `address_stateid: { "greaterThanZero":true },`

This also works fine (in that it DOES NOT validate that address_stateid is greater than zero): `address_stateid: { "greaterThanZero":false },`

However, when I change true/false to be a conditional, such as this, it just behaves as if it is true, regardless of the value of require_state.

```
address_stateid: { "greaterThanZero":function(){return require_state;} },//ALWAYS VALIDATES AS IF require_state IS TRUE
```

the require_state value is set to true or false based on selection of another field.  When this changes, I am outputting the value of 'require_state' to the console,and can see that even when it is set to false, the conditional validation is kicking in, but it shouldn't.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle, i think this will help you achieve your req

```
var require_state = true;
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThanZero", function(value, element) {
 return this.optional(element) || (parseFloat(value) > 0 ||   require_state);
```

}, "* Amount must be greater than zero");

http://jsfiddle.net/Shinov/DfyqE/1/